# how to build dynamic table with vue?

Tags: html-table, vuejs2, vue-component

I tried to find the way build table from the following data property:

```
   data(){
   return {
       headlist: [
    {row: ID},
    {row: Name},
    {row: Title},
    {row: Description },
    {row: Actions }
    ],
    
    }
```

Template code:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
```

Now tried to replace to :

```
           <thead>
           <tr v-repeat="headlist ">
              <th>{{row}}</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
```

Found example from https://012.vuejs.org/guide/list.html

What is wrong my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the documentation for the older version of VueJS. You shouldn't be referring to that. Also, you should be [using the `v-for` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for):

```
<th v-for="(entry, i) in headlist" v-bind:key="i">
  {{ entry.row }}
</th>
```

Proof-of-concept:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      headlist: [{
          row: 'ID'
        },
        {
          row: 'Name'
        },
        {
          row: 'Title'
        },
        {
          row: 'Description'
        },
        {
          row: 'Actions'
        }
      ],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(entry, i) in headlist" v-bind:key="i">
          {{ entry.row }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, first I did not get that code work, but problem was line under my Array.
  bodylist: [skillset.id, skillset.name, skillset.title, skillset.body,  <- this was problem.  Your code work perfectly.